# how to send just one part of an object to template in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I want to send just one part of an object to template.

I Have 2 models like below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_legth=50)
    sure_name = models.CharFiled(max_length=50)

class Office(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_legth=50)
```

and I also created a model like below:

```
class PersonOffice(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
```

now, when I take data from database, by `PersonOffice.objects.all()`,the data is like below:

```
{
    {
        "pk": 0,
        "person": {
            "pk":0,
            "name":"Harry",
            "sure_name":"Potter"
            },
        "office":{
            "pk":5,
            "location":"Toronto"
        }
    },  
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "person": {
            "pk":6,
            "name":"John",
            "sure_name":"Kelly"
            },
        "office":{
            "pk":6,
            "location":"NewYork"
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to send just offices to the template by `render` function. How can I do it?
thanks

***Updated***
I want to use it in template with `{% for %}` loop. for example:

```
{% for office in Offices %}
    <p>Office location: {{ office.location }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I used below code:

```
offices = PersonOffice.objects.all().values('office')
print(offices)
```

and below is the result in terminal:

```
<QuerySet [{'office': 1}, {'office': 2}, {'office': 11}]>
```

Comment: Can you post your views.py file to show where you're currently rendering?

Comment: You seem to be serialising your object before sending to the template, not sure why

Comment: no. I don't serialize them. just for a good way of displaying in here, I display them like json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values)

```
PersonOffice.objects.values('office')
```

This will output a queryset with `office` for each object.

EDIT:

```
PersonOffice.objects.values('office__location')
```

Comment: thank you, I changed the question. by using `values()` i couldn't  use like `{{ office.location }}`. is any other way?

Comment: yes you can use. Values also outputs a queryset. Also see my edit. @msln

Comment: I wrote this code: `{% for office in offices %}{{ office.location }}<br>{% endfor %}` but it doesn't show me anything in the html file

Comment: before render try printing the output of the above query and see what is the output. You might be seeing there something

Comment: if I write just `{% for office in offices %} {{office}} {% endfor %}` it shows me data and the fields that I mentioned in the `values()` function. but I can't use each of them separately.

Comment: @msln print it on the console and post it to the question

Comment: Also try `{% for office in offices %} {{office__location}} {% endfor %}` @msln

Comment: Try the edit. You will see the location if you print this queryset. And you can access those variables in template also